# The Navigation Tabs disappears on mobile view

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am an amateur website designer, and this is my 3rd live website.

I uploaded the website https://www.velvetlotustattoo.com/ last night and everything seemed to work, but on mobile, the tabs for navigation are missing. I am unsure of why it would not be there. Would it be possible for someone else to look at it and let me know if I'm missing something or any other ideas to try?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have given it a display none property somewhere in your code(with media queries I think)

I think you should review your media queries.... If you need more help, you could dm me via my telegram, @lightema.

[image: I have it removed here]